# Scope of Vue Template Syntax Expressions

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In my Vue.js app, a child components emits an event in the following format:

```
 this.$emit('done-editing', payload)
```

My parent component is designed in the following manner:

```
<child-component
 v-on:done-editing="console.log(data)">
</child-component>
```

But when I execute this code, It throws an error saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined

What I understood was the `console` object was not found in this scope. (It is originally defined on the `window` object). I want to know that what is the scope of JavaScript expressions inside `v-on:event="…"` and how to use `console.log` inside Vue template syntax.

I know I can do the same thing as below. But is there a way to do it inside a template expression?

```
<template>
    <child-component
     v-on:done-editing="logMethod(data)">
    </child-component>
</template>
<script>
    methods :  {
       logMethod(data) {
            console.log(data)
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try with `window.console.log`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried earlier with window.console.log() as well. But it did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each handler in a `v-on` directive is "bound to this". That means, when you try to do:

```
v-on:some-event="console.log('test')"
```

You're actually doing:

```
this.console.log('test')
```

Which is not valid because `this` points to the Vue component instance. That's why you can do this:

```
v-on:some-event="someHandler"
…
methods: {
  someHandler() { … }
}
```

Because the expression inside the `v-on` directive is automatically prefixed with this. It calls `this.someHandler` which exists. The same goes for expressions in `v-bind` directives. Specifically, in [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html):

> [...] all Vue handler functions and expressions are strictly bound to the ViewModel that’s handling the current view [...]

[And](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html):

> These expressions will be evaluated as JavaScript in the data scope of the owner Vue instance.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Vue plugin so you can use $window and $document in your templates.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-plugin

This will work after you install the plugin:

```
<child-component
 v-on:done-editing="$window.console.log(data)">
</child-component>
```